# Comment distinguer les noms propres ?

Tags: noms-propres

En particulier les prénoms et noms de familles lorsqu'ils nous sont inconnus.
A part grâce à leur initiale en majuscule, comment peut on les différencier des noms communs, verbes, adverbes, adjectifs en dehors d'une phrase ?

Comment: En dehors d'une phrase, cela peut être parfois ambigu, d'où l'utilité des majuscules quand quelqu'un porte un nom qui s'avère également être un nom commun...

Comment: Et comment le fait-on dans les autres langues? Ceci n'est pas une question propre au français....et puis, les verbes, adverbes et adjectifs se trouvent dans des phrases ou dans les dicos.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this "question" can be applied to any language....

Comment: @Lambie je trouve le motif de clôture particulièrement stupide. Si j'ai demandé ici c'est que ça concerne le français. Vous ne savez faire la distinction dans aucune langue.

Comment: @WaterBearer Pourquoi ne pas poser la question à Language Learning SE ? C'est fait exprès pour ce type de question où la réponse ne dépend pas vraiment de la langue.

Comment: @LukeSawczak comment savez vous que la réponse à cette question ne dépend pas vraiment de la langue ?

Comment: @WaterBearer Posez-la là-bas et j'y répondrai pour que vous voyez ma réponse :) Sinon je le ferai moi-même et copierai le lien ici.

Comment: Ma question concerne le français et je pense que la réponse diffère pour chaque langue donc je n'irai pas poser la question ailleurs où elle sera probablement fermée.

Answer (score 2):

La moitié de la réponse est dans la question, les noms propres commencent par une majuscule. Autre que ça, les noms communs sont accompagnés d'un déterminant comme le, la, les, un, une, des. **Ordinairement** la plupart des noms propres sont invariables (Paris, Joseph, Canada, ...) tandis que les noms communs s'accordent en genre et en nombre. Mais l'ultime réponse est la maîtrise de la langue, quand on connaît suffisamment une langue, la question sera triviale.

Comment: Justement. Une maîtrise de la syntaxe pour reconnaître les locutions où un nom propre n'apparatraît pas, une familiarité avec les règles du discours en ce qui concerne l'introduction d'une nouvelle personne, un vocabulaire assez grand (et le fait d'en être conscient-e) pour pouvoir éliminer les mots connnus ... Tous ces éléments sont nécessaires si on veut deviner correctement dans la plupart des cas.

Comment: Quels noms s'accordent en genre ???

Comment: Selon le contexte, infirmier devient infirmière par exemple.

Comment: Il n'y a malheureusement rien de valable de cette réponse. En dehors d'une phrase les mots ne sont ni accompagnés ni accordés. Et apprendre par cœur une liste (maitriser la langue) suggère qu'il n'y a aucune différence.

Comment: On ne maîtrise pas un langue en apprenant des listes par coeur, la questions est très vague.

Comment: Infirmier et infirmière sont deux noms différents comme cerf et biche, l'un est masculin, l'autre est féminin. Il ne s'agit pas d'accord grammatical comme pour les adjectifs ou les déterminants. Par définition même de la [notion de genre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genre_grammatical), les noms ont un genre fixe. Dans les langues comme le français ou l'allemand, on trouve des paires de noms qui se correspondent pour les animés (animaux et humains) mais il s'agit de deux noms associés...